# How to attach a button to an opengl es object in ios Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, button, opengl-es

I have created a board using OpenGL ES in Xcode. I have made it so the board can be rotated around an axis. I want to place a button on the board, however I have a problem. When the board moves, the button does not, the button stays in its position. How can I "attach" the button to the board, so whenever the board moves, the button will move as well?

Comment: It's a UIButton, or it's a custom OpenGL-rendered button? Just in general: can you provide some more information on the nature of the button and how you've added it?

Comment: I added a UIButton, through main.storyboard

Comment: Quick extra questions. This is presumably ES 2 or 3? So you've direct access to the model-view-projection matrix? Does the button need to rotate or just move its centre?

Comment: Es 2.0, and yes I need the button to rotate with the board.

Comment: I'll need to fire up a project to be confident about the exactly right answer allowing for slightly different coordinate spaces but the essence is going to involve feeding a version of your model-view-projection matrix to the button's `layer.transform`.